How to add telegram bot to channel via KeyboardButtonRequestChat
Safeguard KeyboardButtonRequestChat Result
Cant get bot to join channel after sharing via KeyboardButtonRequestChat, User is the admin of the channel.
Im trying to add my bot to a channel after selecting it through KeyboardButtonRequestChat. the image is a screenshot of what happens after selecting a channel in the SafeGuard Telegram Bot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
